# Issue on populating Excel column based on matched rows

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am working on the below sheet. How I can run a formula to  loop into the column `D` rows and find the exact match in the column `A`  rows and then populate columns `E` and `F` from columns `B` and `C` while `D` and `A` matches?

It would be great if I have this in a Formula instead of running in Macro

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this into E1 and drag it right and down.

```
=iferror(vlookup($D1, $A:$C, column(B:B), false), "")
```